# smartgwt listgrid.getRecordList() not give me updated data

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I'm on my smartgwt project having issue in listgrid.

my listgrid having data come from server side, and user allow to edit any record from that grid.

```
searchGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
searchGrid.setDataSource(searchDS);
searchGrid.setAlwaysShowEditors(true);
```

When I try to edit any cell in grid and try to loop through all record from grid, it doesn't give me latest updated cell which I edited.

I use below code for fetching all records from my listgrid.

```
private String getGridDetails() {

    RecordList records = searchGrid.getRecordList();

    Document doc = XMLParser.createDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ROOT");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    for (int i = 0; i < records.getLength(); i++) {

        Record rec = records.get(i);
        Element row = doc.createElement("ROW");

        for (String str : rec.getAttributes()) {

            String propertyVal = rec.getAttributeAsString(str);

            if (propertyVal != null
                    && propertyVal.equalsIgnoreCase("") != true) {
                Element columnElement = doc
                        .createElement(str.toUpperCase());
                columnElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(propertyVal));
                row.appendChild(columnElement);
            }
        }
        rootElement.appendChild(row);
    }

    return doc.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get every edited and unedited record, you may loop one by one:

```
public Record[] getData(ListGrid grid)
{
    RecordList data = new RecordList();

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.getTotalRows(); i++)
        data.add(grid.getEditedRecord(i));

    return data.duplicate();
}
```

But if you just want to retrieve the edited records, try the following snippet:

```
public static Record[] dameDatosLocalesEditedRows(ListGrid grid)
{
    RecordList data = new RecordList();
    int[] edited = grid.getAllEditRows();

    for (int i = 0; i < edited.length; i++)
        data.add(grid.getEditedRecord(edited[i]));

    return data.duplicate();
}
```